login_cooldown_after not work when workers /multihreading activated -ODOO
To secure production enviornment from Brute force attack Odoo has implemented login_cooldown_after
It working fine when workers = 0
The moment i activate/ put worker >0 it does not work and did not produce failour count
as it not sharing login attempt counter between different process.
what is the alternative solution and is not possible to use login_cooldown_after in multithreading environment?
